# Crystal Report How to sum of field OldAmount from second table where date is less than the provide Param datefield

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, report, formula

i have 2 table named as TB_NewBills and TB_OldPayment , TB_NewBills have colums ClientName ClientID DateofBuying NewBillAmont   and  ![TB_OldPayment][1] have colums cusomterName CustomerID DateofAmount OldAmount

i used 2 paramters in my report Param-clientID and Paam-date upon which i am fetching fields data and fields are displyed on reports are ClientName ClientID DateOfBuying NewBillAmount and in footer i have sum of newBillAmount

Second Part :
**Problem is**   now i want to get the sum of column TB_OldPayment . OldAmount where TB_Old Payment . DateofAmount < param-date  i cant make up with my problem i have done all up to first part please help
image link to see digram http://i58.tinypic.com/99qn7m.jpg
Thx

Comment: you need the sum of the olb bill amount for the same client name as the new bill in the report footer correct?

Answer (score 0):

if you have subreports you will have to create a `shared numbervar variable` for `TB_OldPayment` where you are going to storage a running total of your `OldAmount` where `DateofAmount < param-date`. Then put that formula on your main report on `report  footer`

if you don't have subreport just create a running total of your `OldAmount` where `DateofAmount < param-date` and put on `report  footer`

Comment: can you show me peice of code or steps how to calculate oldAmount with date Condtion thx

Comment: do have subreports or not?

Comment: if you don't have any subreport create a running total, put OldAmount where says field to summarize, type of summary will be sum, evaluate on Use formula(DateofAmount < param-date), reset Never and place it on your report footer

Comment: Thx its work but now problem is i am getting dublicate records and problem coming in running total also calculating the supress records my bad :(

Comment: what is your suppress condition?